# Default value of select in jQuery to getJSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, drop-down-menu

Needing help with the snippet below. Upon a user selecting an option from the `select` the **API URL** is updated for the appropriate days wanted by a user. However, I have set a default value, both in the `select` `option` by using `selected` and by **jQuery** with `$('#DateSelector').val('30')`.

Each does exactly as they are meant to, except the **JSON** data is not loaded on **Page Load**.

How can I get this `value` to pass on **Page Load** so that the default **API URL** gives the correct data.

```js
$('#DateSelector').val('30')

function datePeriod() {
  let datePeriod = $("#DateSelector").val();
  $("#DateShow").html(datePeriod);
  $.getJSON(`https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=API.get&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=last${datePeriod}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`, (data) => {

    //console.log(data);
    let visitors = 0;
    let uniq_visitors = 0;
    let pageviews = 0;
    let uniq_pageviews = 0;
    let actions = 0;
    let outlinks = 0;
    let bounces = 0;
    let avgtime = 0;

    for (i in data) {

      if (data[i].nb_visits) {
        visitors += data[i].nb_visits;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_uniq_visitors) {
        uniq_visitors += data[i].nb_uniq_visitors;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_pageviews) {
        pageviews += data[i].nb_pageviews;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_uniq_pageviews) {
        uniq_pageviews += data[i].nb_uniq_pageviews;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_actions) {
        actions += data[i].nb_actions;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_outlinks) {
        outlinks += data[i].nb_outlinks;
      }
      if (data[i].bounce_count) {
        bounces += data[i].bounce_count;
      }
      if (data[i].avg_time_on_site) {
        avgtime += data[i].avg_time_on_site;
      }
    }

    $("#visitors").html(visitors);
    $("#uniq_visitors").html(uniq_visitors);
    $("#pageviews").html(pageviews);
    $("#uniq_pageviews").html(uniq_pageviews);
    $("#actions").html(actions);
    $("#outlinks").html(outlinks);
    $("#bounces").html(bounces);
    $("#avgtime").html(avgtime / datePeriod);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="DateSelector" id="DateSelector" onchange="datePeriod();">
   <option value="7">Last 7 Days</option>
   <option value="14">Last 14 Days</option>
   <option selected value="30">Last 30 Days</option>
   <option value="90">Last 90 Days</option>
   <option value="365">Last 365 Days</option>
</select>


<span id="visitors"></span>
<span id="uniq_visitors"></span>
<span id="pageviews"></span>
<span id="uniq_pageviews"></span>
<span id="actions"></span>
<span id="outlinks"></span>
<span id="bounces"></span>
<span id="avgtime"></span>
```

Have been through many other questions relating to default values of select but none fit what I am trying to achieve.

**UPDATE**

After applying answer below to use `$('#DateSelector').val('30').trigger("change")` this is a screen recording of what happens.

[image: screen recording]

Using the other answer of

```
$('#DateSelector').val('30')
datePeriod();
```

I get the values of each `object` as `0` on page load
[image: screen recording 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. I have added trigger("change") to your code

`$('#DateSelector').val('30').trigger("change")`

```js
$('#DateSelector').val('30').trigger("change")

function datePeriod() {
  let datePeriod = $("#DateSelector").val();
  $("#DateShow").html(datePeriod);
  $.getJSON(`https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=API.get&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=last${datePeriod}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`, (data) => {

    //console.log(data);
    let visitors = 0;
    let uniq_visitors = 0;
    let pageviews = 0;
    let uniq_pageviews = 0;
    let actions = 0;
    let outlinks = 0;
    let bounces = 0;
    let avgtime = 0;

    for (i in data) {

      if (data[i].nb_visits) {
        visitors += data[i].nb_visits;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_uniq_visitors) {
        uniq_visitors += data[i].nb_uniq_visitors;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_pageviews) {
        pageviews += data[i].nb_pageviews;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_uniq_pageviews) {
        uniq_pageviews += data[i].nb_uniq_pageviews;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_actions) {
        actions += data[i].nb_actions;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_outlinks) {
        outlinks += data[i].nb_outlinks;
      }
      if (data[i].bounce_count) {
        bounces += data[i].bounce_count;
      }
      if (data[i].avg_time_on_site) {
        avgtime += data[i].avg_time_on_site;
      }
    }

    $("#visitors").html(visitors);
    $("#uniq_visitors").html(uniq_visitors);
    $("#pageviews").html(pageviews);
    $("#uniq_pageviews").html(uniq_pageviews);
    $("#actions").html(actions);
    $("#outlinks").html(outlinks);
    $("#bounces").html(bounces);
    $("#avgtime").html(avgtime / datePeriod);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="DateSelector" id="DateSelector" onchange="datePeriod();">
   <option value="7">Last 7 Days</option>
   <option value="14">Last 14 Days</option>
   <option selected value="30">Last 30 Days</option>
   <option value="90">Last 90 Days</option>
   <option value="365">Last 365 Days</option>
</select>


<span id="visitors"></span>
<span id="uniq_visitors"></span>
<span id="pageviews"></span>
<span id="uniq_pageviews"></span>
<span id="actions"></span>
<span id="outlinks"></span>
<span id="bounces"></span>
<span id="avgtime"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just trying to get this working right now. Using your snippet I am not receiving a value on page load. Just looking for any conflict.

Comment: You are not getting the valu on pageload as you are making an API call which takes time to fetch the data and complete the display task. You may need to show a loader while performing the same if the there is a dependency on the api

Comment: I have added a screen recording to the question using your answer. From what I can see there is no conflict unless the other data on the page is getting in the way but I doubt it. Do you have any suggestions that could enforce the `$('#DateSelector').val('30').trigger("change")`? All scripts are loaded above the `select`

Comment: Just to let you know. Your answer was most definitely right - I have many API on the page and that was my issue. I fixed this by `setTimeout(function () { $('#DateSelector').val('30').trigger("change")}, 1000);`. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Darren Cool. Its my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling datePeriod onChange. Instead, call it once on page load and then trigger datePeriod as you are currently doing. What I have done is triggering datePeriod manually once. Check the snippet below,

```js
$('#DateSelector').val('30')
datePeriod();
function datePeriod() {
  let datePeriod = $("#DateSelector").val();
  $("#DateShow").html(datePeriod);
  $.getJSON(`https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=API.get&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=last${datePeriod}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`, (data) => {

    //console.log(data);
    let visitors = 0;
    let uniq_visitors = 0;
    let pageviews = 0;
    let uniq_pageviews = 0;
    let actions = 0;
    let outlinks = 0;
    let bounces = 0;
    let avgtime = 0;

    for (i in data) {

      if (data[i].nb_visits) {
        visitors += data[i].nb_visits;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_uniq_visitors) {
        uniq_visitors += data[i].nb_uniq_visitors;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_pageviews) {
        pageviews += data[i].nb_pageviews;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_uniq_pageviews) {
        uniq_pageviews += data[i].nb_uniq_pageviews;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_actions) {
        actions += data[i].nb_actions;
      }
      if (data[i].nb_outlinks) {
        outlinks += data[i].nb_outlinks;
      }
      if (data[i].bounce_count) {
        bounces += data[i].bounce_count;
      }
      if (data[i].avg_time_on_site) {
        avgtime += data[i].avg_time_on_site;
      }
    }

    $("#visitors").html(visitors);
    $("#uniq_visitors").html(uniq_visitors);
    $("#pageviews").html(pageviews);
    $("#uniq_pageviews").html(uniq_pageviews);
    $("#actions").html(actions);
    $("#outlinks").html(outlinks);
    $("#bounces").html(bounces);
    $("#avgtime").html(avgtime / datePeriod);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="DateSelector" id="DateSelector" onchange="datePeriod();">
   <option value="7">Last 7 Days</option>
   <option value="14">Last 14 Days</option>
   <option selected value="30">Last 30 Days</option>
   <option value="90">Last 90 Days</option>
   <option value="365">Last 365 Days</option>
</select>


<span id="visitors"></span>
<span id="uniq_visitors"></span>
<span id="pageviews"></span>
<span id="uniq_pageviews"></span>
<span id="actions"></span>
<span id="outlinks"></span>
<span id="bounces"></span>
<span id="avgtime"></span>
```

Comment: This works but not a reliable solution as the moment you change the onChange function to something else it will stop working. For the sake of code maintainability use tigger("change") as mentioned by me in my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it returns a value on page load but `0` until the select option is chosen.

Comment: Sorry but I did not follow. When do you get zero?

Comment: the data returned for `id="visitors"` `id="uniq_visitors"`... is zero on Page Load.

Comment: That is strange. I am getting 50 and 38 for them by default

Comment: Very strange. I have added a screen recording above in my question to show this.

Comment: It seems that your suggestion is using `let uniq_visitors = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

While setting the default value using Jquery,
`$('#DateSelector').val('30').trigger('change');`

may solve your issue.